# Trouble scanning barcode

Tags: c#, textbox, barcode, symbols

I'm having a problem with scanning a barcode with a Symbol scanner. What the scanner does, is it reads the barcode and then returns it as basic keyboard strokes.

I now made a very simple Windows Forms apps which just needs to validate barcodes. However, I'm having trouble finding out when the scanner is actually done scanning. It wasn't a problem before because ALL barcodes would always have 12 symbols, so I could just use the following check on the OnTextChangedEvent of a textbox:
    if (txtBarcode.Text.Length == 12)

However, as of recently a barcode can ALSO contain 13 symbols, which makes my check useless, since it will skip the last character if the barcode has 13 symbols.

I can't seem to figure out how to find out if the scanner is actually done scanning (done triggering keyboard strokes). I need to find out when the scanner is done scanning (it doesn't matter if the barcode has 12 or 13 symbols) and if it is, I need to execute some action.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: If you are using a specific type of barcode scanner , check the manual . Probably there is a setting that adds an escape character or something when it finishes the "typing" .Thus you only have to check for that character . And probably you should not only think of the barcode as basic key keystrokes.. for me it's more like copy-paste.
The settings in the scanner are barcodes themselves .

Comment: Thank you! Because of you, I found out that the scanner "presses" the Enter button once it's done scanning. Now the amount of symbols in the barcode doesn't matter anymore, as long as I know it's done scanning.

Answer (score 0):

The Symbol brand is now own by [Zebra Technologies](https://www.zebra.com/us/en.html/).

You can find information about how to configure the scanner on their [support website](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN) and, using the [123Scan v2 utility](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/scanning-systems/scanner-drivers-and-utilities/123scan2-configuration-utility.html) you can configure the scanner so that it can include the barcode data between a pre-amble and a post-amble. So you can know exactly when you hare receiving the data from the scanner.

On top of that you can do more fancy stuff using the scanner driver and then have more control on it. As an example you can enable the scanner only when you actually need to read some data.

If you have more question about the scanner and how to use them, you can take a look at Zebra Technologies [developer website Launchpad](https://developer.zebra.com), that has [an area on this technologies](https://developer.zebra.com/community/technologies/advanced-data-capture).

*Disclaimer*: I work for Zebra Technologies.